# How do I implement a nested ArrayList and iterate through them in Android Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to create a structure where there will be a list of multiple String values e.g. "0212" and I want to have three ArrayLists. The first ArrayList will take the first part of the value "02", the second will take the second part "1" and the third will take the third value "2". I then want to be able to iterate through the list of values so that I can find the specific one quicker as multiple values will have the same value for the first and second part of the value. I then want to link that to an object that has a value matching "0212". I hope that someone understands what I am trying to explain and if anyone can help me, I would much appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

This is the code that I have at the moment which matches the string value against the DataObject address value in the ArrayList:

```
public void setUpValues()
{   
    String otherString = "4210";

    Iterator<DataObject> it = dataObjects.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        DataObject currentDataObject = it.next();
        if(currentDataObject.getAddress().equals(otherString))
        {
            System.out.println("IT WORKSSSSSS!");
            currentDataObject.setValue("AHHHHHHHHH");

            System.out.println("Data Object Address: " + currentDataObject.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Data Object Type: " + currentDataObject.getType());
            System.out.println("Data Object Value: " + currentDataObject.getValue());
            System.out.println("Data Object Range: " + currentDataObject.getRange());
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: make a Bean class and use it ArrayList<BeanClass>

Comment: could you please look at the code that I have just added and see what you would suggest, thank you

Comment: wont the size of 0212 will change? is it always divided into 3 parts

Comment: @JamesMeade Generally speaking, it sounds like the data structure you're describing is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). If you can make a strong assumption about the values that you're storing, though, then a simpler solution might be to use a `Map<String, ArrayList<DataObject>>`. What assumptions can you make about the values in this data structure?

Comment: The value will actually be more like "000110" and will be a hex binary format. I want to break down each couple so that there is 3 sections and each section will be a byte. So it will be a byte[3].

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are so tightly defined (three sections, each represented by one byte), I think you can build a lightweight solution based on `Map`:

```
Map<Byte, ArrayList<Byte>> firstSegments;
Map<Byte, ArrayList<Byte>> secondSegments;
Map<Byte, FinalObject> thirdSegments;
```

where `FinalObject` is the fully assembled data type (e.g., `Byte[3]`). This provides efficient lookup by segment, but you'll need to iterate over the arrays to find the "next" group of segments to check. Roughly:

```
Byte[3] needle = ...;
Byte firstSeg = ...;
Byte secondSeg = ...;
Byte thirdSeg = ...;

for (Byte b1 : firstSegments.get(firstSeg)) {
    if (b1.equals(secondSeg)) {
        for (Byte b2 : secondSegments.get(b1)) {
            if (b2.equals(thirdSeg)) {
                return thirdSegments.get(b2); // found a match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear from your question, but if you're trying to decide whether a given `Byte` segment is in one of the arrays and don't care about iterating over them, it would be cleaner and more efficient to use a `Set<Byte>` instead of `ArrayList<Byte>`. `Set` provides a fast `contains()` method for this purpose.